# Using $(this) in another function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/y5Lk5k5t/

```
function check() {
  $('input').each(function(i, val) {
    $(this).val() ? "" : console.log($(this).attr('placeholder') + ' cannot be empty.');
  });
}

$('button').click(function() {
  check();
})
```

I want to create a function call checkIfEmpty, how do I separate it from the each function? I did this but it doesn't work.

```
$('input').each(function(){
        if(!$(this).val()){
            require($(this));
        }
    });

    function require(that){
        console('Please fill in ' + $(that).data('validate-msg') + '.');
    }
```

Comment: You're passing `$(this)` to `require()` as a jQuery object, you don't need `$(that).data...`, just use `that.data...`

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `$(this)` to `require` you don't have to convert it into a jQuery object again, so this should work:

```
function require(that){
    console('Please fill in ' + that.data('validate-msg') + '.');
}
```

Edit: This is a bit faster and more readable:

```
$('input').each(function() {
    var currentInput = $(this);
    if(!currentInput.val()) {
        var message = currentInput.data('validate-msg');
        require(message);
    }
});

function require (message) {
    console('Please fill in ' + message + '.');
}
```

Comment: That does not matter I guess. `$(this)`, `$($(this))`, `$($($(this)))` all evaluate to same object.

Answer (score 0):

This version works:

```js
    function check() {
    
        $('input').each(function () {
            if (!($(this).val())) {
                require($(this));
            }
        });
    
        function require($that) {
            console.log('Please fill in ' + $that.data('validate-msg') + '.');
        }
    }
    
    $('button').click(function () {
    
        check();
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="name" data-validate-msg="one">
<input type="text" placeholder="email" data-validate-msg="two">

<button>submit</button>
```

And an updated jsfilddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1kpq8asq/1/

Answer (score 0):

As a small note, avoid using such names as "require" in your "usual" code. In case of reusing your code in NodeJS environment, for example, it will be broken.